# MySQL select records where timetamp = equal hours

Tags: mysql

I have many records in the table. I need to choose only those whose unix timestamp = 21, 22, 23 hours (equal hours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OP's timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682523/mysql-select-records-where-timetamp-equal-hours/52682531?noredirect=1#comment92293281_52682531) is Unix Time in seconds, and he [needs to match the exact hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682523/mysql-select-records-where-timetamp-equal-hours/52682531?noredirect=1#comment92294031_52682531), like `21:00:00` and so on.

- We can use [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function to convert Unix timestamp to MySQL datetime format **'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'**
- Now, we can use [`HOUR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) function to get hour value from a MySQL datetime. Similarly, we use [`Minute()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute) and [`Second()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_second) function to get minute and second values from the datetime, respectively. To match hour values, minute and second value should be zero.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(your_time_column)) IN (21, 22, 23)
  AND MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(your_time_column)) = 0 
  AND SECOND(FROM_UNIXTIME(your_time_column)) = 0
```

---

If the time column is in MySQL datetime format, we can directly use the `Hour()` function:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE HOUR(your_time_column) IN (21,22,23) 
  AND MINUTE(your_time_column) = 0 
  AND SECOND(your_time_column) = 0
```

Comment: But.. my unix timestamp it is saved in the INT format in mysql and I get a warning: incorret datetime value...Can it be done differently?

Comment: @LukaszStaszewski check the latest updated answer now.

Comment: Thanks. But.. The query shows me all records (also with minutes)

Comment: @LukaszStaszewski can you edit your question to add some sample data. Without looking at your data, it will be wild guesses only. We dont need your exact data. You can share some representative data, with expected output

Comment: Here is my table: https://i.imgur.com/e64Hxto.png. I need to select the servers whose timestamp contains full hours

Comment: @LukaszStaszewski run `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP) FROM your_table` and share the image of this query's results on ur table

Comment: @LukaszStaszewski This should work: `SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(your_time_column)) IN (21, 22, 23)`

What is this query's output you are getting ?  And if it is not correct, what is the issue ?

Comment: This query displays all records (does not pay attention to full hours... https://i.imgur.com/oTc5VCT.png

Comment: @LukaszStaszewski So you need only those rows where time is exactly like 21:00:00 hours ?

Comment: Records whose time is, for example, 21:00, 22:00 (for seconds we can not pay attention because the records are added one by one and have a different timestamp - eg 21:00:00, 21:00:01, 21:00:02)

Comment: @LukaszStaszewski please check the updated answer. You could make changes to it as it now gets Minute and second values also

Comment: Thanks for your interest and help. I will check it tomorrow and let you know :)